# Access a varibale from MainActivity class to another class

Tags: java, android, json, variables, global-variables

I have a `JSONObject` in my `MainActivity` under a function and I want to use it outside the function and in another class, how can I do that?

I want to make this variable `public`, here is the code :

```
public void ListDrwaer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> productList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("products");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

            }
          //  System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(0));
            List<Map<String, String>> productLista = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            JSONObject pro1 = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(1);
            String data = pro1.getString("name");
        //    System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + data);


            System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + pro1);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I want to make `pro1` (which is `JSONObject`) `public` and use it outside `public void` and also use it in another class.

Can I do that using put or add?

Comment: I think you can set it as public variable, then in another classes/activities, call MainActivity.pro1

Comment: I get Modifier public not allowed here error when I want to do that under public void.

Comment: public directly under 'public class MainActivity extends...'

Answer (score 0):

try code below, it might help..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: define pro1 as a public static variable, then you can use it in any class elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the variable first outside any method like this

```
Static JSONObject pro1;
```

and then acces it simple by using

```
classname.pro1
```

Comment: Did this. I get this : Field 'pro1' is never used.

Comment: Yes because in you listDrwaer you have to change JSONObject pro1 to only pro1 so it doesnt get set again to a private method

Answer (score 0):

1. you can declare that variable public.
   just put

   public static JSONObject pro1;

to your class declaration.
2. that is not safe because of: 
1. that variable will vanish if your app will be killed and recreated by Android system.
2. you should be carefull when accessing that variable from other threads.